Не запускается sh скрипт из под php
В консоле
sh /var/www/bash.sh

Скрипт работает, в скрипте команды ffmpeg...
Из под php, при попытке запустить скрипт
exec("$(sh /var/www/bash.sh)");
exec("sh /var/www/bash.sh");

Не выходит, погрузит html страницу и сбрасывает. Скрипт добавляет файлы в каталог, запуск из консоли, файлы есть. Запуск из под php, отваливается, файлов нету...

сам скрипт что-нибудь выводит? выведи результат работы скрипта $code = 0; $output = []; exec("sh /var/www/bash.sh", $output, $code); var_dump($code); var_dump($output);

Вариант 1.
В начало своего shell-скрипта добавьте явное указание интерпретатора ответственного за выполнение кода скрипта. В Вашем случае это sh - его местоположение можете посмотреть командами locate sh или whereis sh, обычно это /usr/bin. Итак, добавляем в начале скрипта строку
#!/usr/bin/sh

После чего сделайте свой shell-скрипт исполняемым, для этого с помощью команды chmod навешайте на него флаг x (eXecutable)
chmod +x /var/www/bash.sh

Теперь Вы можете запускать это файл как любую другую программу и соответственно вызывать напрямую в exec
exec('/var/www/bash.sh');

Вариант 2.
PHP-скрипты вызываемые на стороне веб-сервера, как правило запускаются от имени того же пользователя, что и сам веб-сервер. Обычно это пользователь www-data. Этот пользователь не знает где расположены программы в ОС в отличии от обычных пользователей, которые после входа узнают о всех путях к программам прописанных в переменной окружения PATH. Таким образом, все что Вам нужно - указать полный путь к интерпретатору sh (как найти его местоположение я уже указал в Варианте 1) при вызове через exec
exec('/usr/bin/sh /var/www/bash.sh');

